# Bootstrap width getting overflown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Picture showung address gettung expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kcwq.png)

Text not containing withing Bootstrap column structure

I have tried adding width =100%

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
        <div width="200px">
            <strong>Quote ID: </strong>{!quoteValue.Name}<br/>
            <strong>Quote Date: </strong>{!quoteDate}<br/>
            <strong>Contact: </strong>{!quoteContactName}<br/>
            <strong>Address: </strong>{!quoteAddress}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
        <div>Your Health Representative:
        </div><strong>{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}</strong>
            <div>{!$User.Phone}</div>
        <div><a href="mailto:{!$User.Email}">{!$User.Email}</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
        <div>Notes:<br/><small>This is NOT a bill. It is an illustrative quote, based on the census information provided. Please contact your Broker for details on how to move forward with Universal Health Fellowship products.</small></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Need to contain the quoteAddress withing column structure

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it with the css `word-break` style. Per default, long words (without spaces) are not broken into smaller parts. You can set for example

```
.col-md-4 {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

[Demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)